# Runtime permissions breaks backwards-compatibility

Tags: android, android-permissions

I recently upgraded my app to SDK 23 so I could implement the runtime permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. I implemented per this document: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Everything works great on Lollipop but permissions broke in Gingerbread. `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` always returns `PERMISSION_DENIED` and `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` does nothing. *However I know my app has permission because I'm able to access files on the sd card.*

Are the methods backwards-compatible or am I supposed to use `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)` in my code?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `am I supposed to use if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) in my code?` Yes, you are.

Comment: That actually sounds like a bug.  ContextCompat is supposed to work API 4.

Comment: @Rotwang What's the point of the support library, then? Why even implement the new methods on Gingerbread if they do nothing? It seems to me that pre-Lollipop checkSelfPermission() should always return PERMISSION_GRANTED.

Comment: `What's the point of the support library, then?` to provide VectorDrawables to the older API Levels, for instance. And many other **objects** which have been added to the later OS versions.

Comment: @Rotwang That doesn't explain why the support library provides those methods.

Comment: You see, since API Level 19, the Alarm system has been completely destro... rethought. And now we must check the API Level to act some how or some differently. The same is for permissions after the advent of Android OS 6.0+. But we still need the support library to give Fragments and the ActionBar to API Levels lower than 11. And VectorDrawables to API Levels lower than 23. And many more objects.

Comment: It works for many, many other apps. Include your code.